# Web App throwing IDX21323 in teams app studio

Tags: .net, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-teams, microsoft-appstudio

I have a web app developed on .NET MVC that uses azure ad authentication. The web app works perfectly fine in authentication in localhost and also on deploying in azure. Authentication working fine.
Now I am deploying app in teams using app studio. Since the user in ad is already logged in teams, user should automatically pass authentication and go to redirect page. But its throwing IDX21323 error.

**IDX21323: RequireNonce is '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'. OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null, OpenIdConnectProtocol.ValidatedIdToken.Payload.Nonce was not null. The nonce cannot be validated. If you don't need to check the nonce, set OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.RequireNonce to 'false'. Note if a 'nonce' is found it will be evaluated.**

[OpenIdConnectProtocolInvalidNonceException: IDX21323: RequireNonce is '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'. OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null, OpenIdConnectProtocol.ValidatedIdToken.Payload.Nonce was not null. The nonce cannot be validated. If you don't need to check the nonce, set OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.RequireNonce to 'false'. Note if a 'nonce' is found it will be evaluated.]
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.ValidateNonce(OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext validationContext) +1374
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.ValidateAuthenticationResponse(OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext validationContext) +219
Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.d__9.MoveNext() +3744
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +27
Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.d__9.MoveNext() +5436
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.d__31.MoveNext() +452
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.d__5.MoveNext() +217
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.d__7.MoveNext() +179
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.d__5.MoveNext() +519
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
Kentor.OwinCookieSaver.d__2.MoveNext() +196
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.d__7.MoveNext() +179
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.d__12.MoveNext() +180
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar) +69
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult ar) +64
System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +429
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +50
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +163

Comment: Have you modified your tab to deal with living in a Teams context? As an example, when your app is being served as a Teams tab, are you calling microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate? If not, please read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-tab-aad . If your page is ONLY meant to run in Teams, then you can change it as necessary. If it needs to be hosted AND standalone (e.g. Non Teams mode), then you need to detect if you're in a Teams context first

Comment: The authentication code that they are suggesting where should I put that. And also the button on home page should I create it. Can i assign the js function to already existing sign in button